# How to Pass Two Columns from Database to one Datatable Cell

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

Am trying to Pass more than one column to the php file using ajax i want to display more than one column in one data cell.

this is the code that works for one colunm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable({
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "fname"},
                    {"data": "phoneno"},
                    {"data": "email"},
                    {"data": "idno"},
                    {"data": "idno"},
                    {"data": "status"}

                ], 

                "processing": true,
                "fixedHeader": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    url: '../lib/request/viewrequests.php',
                    type: 'POST'
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How do i Change the above to pass two columns in `{"data": ""}`

Comment: You would need to do it in a rendering callback. All the row dat is exposed there and you can format the html / text any way you want for any given cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to define a rendering function.

For example:

```js
"columns": [
    {"data": "fname"},
    {"data": "phoneno"},
    {"data": "email"},
    {"data": "idno"},
    {"data": "status"},
    {
       "data": null,
       "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
          return full["idno"] + ", " + full["status"];
       }
    }
],
```

Comment: it works but when i search i get an error reffering me to datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: @Gyrocode.com,I have one doubt, for example, I have to always return full["idno"] and I have to return full["status"] depending upon the condition then How can I do? like "render":function(data, type, full, meta){ return full["idno" ; switch(full["status"])  <!---case code here->} so I will get output full["idno"] and full["status"](depanding upon the case return)